# Survey, ability to view attached document specific to the question

Tags: survey

We're looking to have an online portal where our customers are able to sign in.

Within the portal, we want to create questions that are mostly yes/no questions. Next, we will select the customers to send the questionnaire to.

Also, for specific questions, we want to add an attachment. Depending on the question a Word document will be attached to be viewed by the customer. On top of that, we need a confirmation that they have "Read and Agree" the document they have just read.

For example, the attached document would have some policies they need to follow prior to visiting the site, after they have read it - they need to agree they have "Read" the policy and "Agree" with our policies.

Answer (score 2):

With a [PollUnit Survey](https://pollunit.com/en/survey) you can require participants to accept your own terms and conditions. If you add a "Submit Rating" step about "Pictures, music or files" you can upload your Documents. In combination with a simple "Yes" or "Yes/No" vote participants can check your documents. If you add a description with a request to read and accept the documents, it might help you.

Example step with terms and conditions:

[image: Survey start with terms and conditions]

Example step with documents:

[image: Docs with checkmarks]

Disclosure: I work for PollUnit